# How to decode a string in scala to json payload?

Tags: scala

I have a sample event which contains a string encoded value which has to decoded.What is the best way to decode and make it as json payload to load into kinesis.

```
    "errors": [
      {
        "level": "error",
        "message": "error: instance value (\"category\") not found in enum (possible values: [\"article\",\"section\",\"account\",\"subscription\",\"game\",\"tool\",\"stock\",\"gallery\",\"slideshow\",\"video\",\"error\",\"utility\",\"page\",\"funnel\",\"conversion\",\"(not provided)\"])\n    level: \"error\"\n    schema: {\"loadingURI\":\"#\",\"pointer\":\"/properties/type\"}\n    instance: {\"pointer\":\"/type\"}\n    domain: \"validation\"\n    keyword: \"enum\"\n    value: \"category\"\n    enum: [\"article\",\"section\",\"account\",\"subscription\",\"game\",\"tool\",\"stock\",\"gallery\",\"slideshow\",\"video\",\"error\",\"utility\",\"page\",\"funnel\",\"conversion\",\"(not provided)\"]\n"
      }
    ],
    "failure_tstamp": "2021-02-22T18:30:06.276Z",
    "line": "CwBkAAAADjE5Mi4xNDMuNTcuMjAyCgDIAAABd8sBcjwLANIAAAAFVVRGLTgLANwAAAASc3NjLTAuMTUuMC1raW5lc2lzCwEsAAAAbU1vemlsbGEvNS4wIChpUGhvbmU7IENQVSBpUGhvbmUgT1MgMTRfNCBsaWtlIE1hYyBPUyBYKSBBcHBsZVdlYktpdC82MDUuMS4xNSAoS0hUTUwsIGxpa2UgR2Vja28pIE1vYmlsZS8xNUUxNDgLATYAAAAhaHR0cHM6Ly9wdWJhZHMuZy5kb3VibGVjbGljay5uZXQvCwFAAAAAIy9jb20uc25vd3Bsb3dhbmFseXRpY3Muc25vd3Bsb3cvdHAyCwFUAAAKz3sic2NoZW1hIjoiaWdsdTpjb20uc25vd3Bsb3dhbmFseXRpY3Muc25vd3Bsb3cvcGF5bG9hZF9kYXRhL2pzb25zY2hlbWEvMS0wLTQiLCJkYXRhIjpbeyJlIjoidWUiLCJ1ZV9wciI6IntcInNjaGVtYVwiOlwiaWdsdTpjb20uc25vd3Bsb3dhbmFseXRpY3Muc25vd3Bsb3cvdW5zdHJ1Y3RfZXZlbnQvanNvbnNjaGVtYS8xLTAtMFwiLFwiZGF0YVwiOntcInNjaGVtYVwiOlwiaWdsdTpjb20uZ2xvYmVhbmRtYWlsL2NvbnRlbnRfaW1wcmVzc2lvbnMvanNvbnNjaGVtYS8xLTAtNVwiLFwiZGF0YVwiOntcImNvbnRlbnRcIjpbe1widG9wXCI6MixcImhlaWdodFwiOjE4MyxcIndpZHRoXCI6MzAwLFwiaWRcIjpcIjYzODk2Y2IwLWM2MWUtNDRiZi1iOGZmLWVmNWM3OGIwMjRlZVwiLFwiZmVhdHVyZVwiOlwicHJvbW8gYXBwIHM3MXg3MCBsb2FkZWRcIixcImxhYmVsXCI6XCJhIGxvb2sgYXQgdGhlIGZpcnN0IHRlbGwtYWxsIHRvIHNoYWtlIHRoZSByb3lhbHNcIixcInRvdGFsXCI6MSxcImFjdGlvblwiOlwiaW4tdmlld1wiLFwidHlwZVwiOlwic29waGktbWFya2V0aW5nLWNvbnRhaW5lclwiLFwidGltZXN0YW1wXCI6MTYxNDAxODYwNTAyMX1dfX19IiwidHYiOiJqcy0yLjE3LjAiLCJ0bmEiOiJzb3BoaVRhZyIsImFpZCI6Im5ld3MyNC13ZWJzaXRlIiwicCI6IndlYiIsInR6IjoiQWZyaWNhL0pvaGFubmVzYnVyZyIsImxhbmciOiJlbi1nYiIsImNzIjoiVVRGLTgiLCJyZXMiOiI0MTR4ODk2IiwiY2QiOiIzMiIsImNvb2tpZSI6IjEiLCJlaWQiOiI3Y2FkMjdlOC0xN2Y1LTQ5ODAtYmZkMi1jNzUyNTE2MDk4YzgiLCJkdG0iOiIxNjE0MDE4NjA1MDMzIiwiY28iOiJ7XCJzY2hlbWFcIjpcImlnbHU6Y29tLnNub3dwbG93YW5hbHl0aWNzLnNub3dwbG93L2NvbnRleHRzL2pzb25zY2hlbWEvMS0wLTBcIixcImRhdGFcIjpbe1wic2NoZW1hXCI6XCJpZ2x1OmNvbS5nbG9iZWFuZG1haWwvY29ubmVjdG9yL2pzb25zY2hlbWEvMS0wLTRcIixcImRhdGFcIjp7XCJwYWdlVmlld1VVSURcIjpcIjBhZTBmNmQ2LTQ5OWQtNDNlNy1hMjM4LWVkMWIyZTNkYWMyOVwifX0se1wic2NoZW1hXCI6XCJpZ2x1OmNvbS5nbG9iZWFuZG1haWwvZW52aXJvbm1lbnQvanNvbnNjaGVtYS8xLTAtOFwiLFwiZGF0YVwiOntcInN0YXRlXCI6XCJhY3RpdmVcIixcImVudmlyb25tZW50XCI6XCJwcm9kXCIsXCJjbGllbnRcIjpcIm1lZGlhMjRcIixcImNsaWVudENvbmZpZ1ZlcnNpb25cIjpcIjEuNFwiLFwiaXNBZEJsb2NrXCI6ZmFsc2UsXCJ0cmFja2VyVmVyc2lvblwiOlwiMi4xLjhcIixcInNjcmVlbk9yaWVudGF0aW9uXCI6XCJsYW5kc2NhcGVcIn19LHtcInNjaGVtYVwiOlwiaWdsdTpjb20uZ2xvYmVhbmRtYWlsL3Zpc2l0b3IvanNvbnNjaGVtYS8xLTAtNlwiLFwiZGF0YVwiOntcInR5cGVcIjpcIlJlZ2lzdGVyZWRcIixcImlzTG9nZ2VkSW5cIjp0cnVlfX0se1wic2NoZW1hXCI6XCJpZ2x1OmNvbS5nbG9iZWFuZG1haWwvcGFnZS9qc29uc2NoZW1hLzEtMC0xMVwiLFwiZGF0YVwiOntcInR5cGVcIjpcImNhdGVnb3J5XCIsXCJicmVhZGNydW1iXCI6XCJzcG9ydDp0b3BzdG9yaWVzOlwiLFwic2VjdGlvbk5hbWVcIjpcIihub3QgcHJvdmlkZWQpXCJ9fSx7XCJzY2hlbWFcIjpcImlnbHU6Y29tLnNub3dwbG93YW5hbHl0aWNzLnNub3dwbG93L2NsaWVudF9zZXNzaW9uL2pzb25zY2hlbWEvMS0wLTFcIixcImRhdGFcIjp7XCJ1c2VySWRcIjpcIjAxM2QxMThjLTJmNTQtNGY1MS1hYzJkLTBhNGNhY2Q1ZGRlM1wiLFwic2Vzc2lvbklkXCI6XCJjMGEzZjIxOC1mM2VjLTQzYzYtYmUwZC0zNTJjMzFiNDdjNWFcIixcInNlc3Npb25JbmRleFwiOjY3MixcInByZXZpb3VzU2Vzc2lvbklkXCI6bnVsbCxcInN0b3JhZ2VNZWNoYW5pc21cIjpcIlNRTElURVwifX1dfSIsInZwIjoiMzAweDI1MCIsImRzIjoiMzAweDI1MCIsInZpZCI6IjE1OSIsInNpZCI6IjkwOTkzZWUyLTkwOGMtNDFkYS04YmZmLThhZTlhNjUzMGM2ZSIsImR1aWQiOiIxNjBmNDIzYy0yMjdjLTQ0YjYtOTI2Mi0zYzA3MjY1NjhiM2MiLCJ1aWQiOiJLM3d2bkhZQlRLZkpIZ2VDTExGNDNtR0FiMWQyIiwidXJsIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly9wdWJhZHMuZy5kb3VibGVjbGljay5uZXQvZ2FtcGFkL2Fkcz9jYXBzPWludGVyYWN0aXZlVmlkZW9faW5saW5lVmlkZW9fbXJhaWQxX21yYWlkMl9tcmFpZDNfdGhfYXV0b3BsYXlfbWVkaWF0aW9uX2F2X3Nka0FkbW9iQXBpRm9yQWRzX2RpX3RyYW5zcGFyZW50QmFja2dyb3VuZF9zZGtWaWRlb19hc29fc2Z2X2Rpbm1fZGltX25hdl9uYXZjX2N0X3Njcm9sbF9kaW5tb19nbHNfc2FpTWFjcm9fY3BjYmdfb21pZEVuYWJsZWRfZ2NhY2hlX2Fib2lfeFNlY29uZHMmZWlkPTMxODQ4MjQ2MSUyQzMxODQ5MjQ5NiZmb3JtYXQ9MzIweDUwX2FzJmpzPWFmbWEtc2RrLWktdjcuNjQuMCZwcmVxcz0xMTk1JnNlcV9udW09MTk4MyNjYXBzPWludGVyYWN0aXZlVmlkZW9faW5saW5lVmlkZW9fbXJhaWQxX21yYWlkMl9tcmFpZDNfdGhfYXV0b3BsYXlfbWVkaWF0aW9uX2F2X3Nka0FkbW9iQXBpRm9yQWRzX2RpX3RyYW5zcGFyZW50QmFja2dyb3VuZF9zZGtWaWRlb19hc29fc2Z2X2Rpbm1fZGltX25hdl9uYXZjX2N0X3Njcm9sbF9kaW5tb19nbHNfc2FpTWFjcm9fY3BjYmdfb21pZEVuYWJsZWRfZ2NhY2hlX2Fib2lfeFNlY29uZHMmZWlkPTMxODQ4MjQ2MSUyNTJDMzE4NDkyNDk2JmZvcm1hdD0zMjB4NTBfYXMmanM9YWZtYS1zZGstaS12Ny42NC4wJnByZXFzPTExOTUmc2VxX251bT0xOTgzIiwic3RtIjoiMTYxNDAxODYwNTM5MSJ9XX0PAV4LAAAADwAAAB9Ib3N0OiBlbmRwb2ludC5zb3BoaS5uZXdzMjQuY29tAAAAeVVzZXItQWdlbnQ6IE1vemlsbGEvNS4wIChpUGhvbmU7IENQVSBpUGhvbmUgT1MgMTRfNCBsaWtlIE1hYyBPUyBYKSBBcHBsZVdlYktpdC82MDUuMS4xNSAoS0hUTUwsIGxpa2UgR2Vja28pIE1vYmlsZS8xNUUxNDgAAAALQWNjZXB0OiAqLyoAAAAiQWNjZXB0LUVuY29kaW5nOiBnemlwLCBkZWZsYXRlLCBicgAAABZBY2NlcHQtTGFuZ3VhZ2U6IGVuLXVzAAAAKE9yaWdpbjogaHR0cHM6Ly9wdWJhZHMuZy5kb3VibGVjbGljay5uZXQAAAAqUmVmZXJlcjogaHR0cHM6Ly9wdWJhZHMuZy5kb3VibGVjbGljay5uZXQvAAAAH1gtRm9yd2FyZGVkLUZvcjogMTkyLjE0My41Ny4yMDIAAAArWC1Gb3J3YXJkZWQtSG9zdDogZW5kcG9pbnQuc29waGkubmV3czI0LmNvbQAAABVYLUZvcndhcmRlZC1Qb3J0OiA0NDMAAAAYWC1Gb3J3YXJkZWQtUHJvdG86IGh0dHBzAAAARFgtRm9yd2FyZGVkLVNlcnZlcjogdHJhZWZpay1leHRlcm5hbC1yZWQtdHJhZWZpay1oYS02Yzg2ODY5NDc5LWN4c3JzAAAAGVgtUmVhbC1JcDogMTkyLjE0My41Ny4yMDIAAAAbVGltZW91dC1BY2Nlc3M6IDxmdW5jdGlvbjE+AAAAEGFwcGxpY2F0aW9uL2pzb24LAWgAAAAQYXBwbGljYXRpb24vanNvbgsBkAAAABllbmRwb2ludC5zb3BoaS5uZXdzMjQuY29tCwGaAAAAJDY3NThlNDEzLWViMjQtNDJhOC05NmU5LTBiY2JhNGE0YmMxZQt6aQAAAEFpZ2x1OmNvbS5zbm93cGxvd2FuYWx5dGljcy5zbm93cGxvdy9Db2xsZWN0b3JQYXlsb2FkL3RocmlmdC8xLTAtMAA="
}
```

I was trying to read as below in code but its not

```
val sJson = JsonMethods.parse("{\n    \"errors\": [\n      {\n        \"level\": \"error\",\n        \"message\": \"error: instance value (\\\"category\\\") not found in enum (possible values: [\\\"article\\\",\\\"section\\\",\\\"account\\\",\\\"subscription\\\",\\\"game\\\",\\\"tool\\\",\\\"stock\\\",\\\"gallery\\\",\\\"slideshow\\\",\\\"video\\\",\\\"error\\\",\\\"utility\\\",\\\"page\\\",\\\"funnel\\\",\\\"conversion\\\",\\\"(not provided)\\\"])\\n    level: \\\"error\\\"\\n    schema: {\\\"loadingURI\\\":\\\"#\\\",\\\"pointer\\\":\\\"/properties/type\\\"}\\n    instance: {\\\"pointer\\\":\\\"/type\\\"}\\n    domain: \\\"validation\\\"\\n    keyword: \\\"enum\\\"\\n    value: \\\"category\\\"\\n    enum: [\\\"article\\\",\\\"section\\\",\\\"account\\\",\\\"subscription\\\",\\\"game\\\",\\\"tool\\\",\\\"stock\\\",\\\"gallery\\\",\\\"slideshow\\\",\\\"video\\\",\\\"error\\\",\\\"utility\\\",\\\"page\\\",\\\"funnel\\\",\\\"conversion\\\",\\\"(not provided)\\\"]\\n\"\n      }\n    ],\n    \"failure_tstamp\": \"2021-02-22T18:30:06.276Z\",\n    \"line\": \"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\"\n}")
val payloadJsonValue = sJson \ "line"
val payvalue = JsonMethods.compact(JsonMethods.render(payloadJsonValue)).replace("\"", "")
val payloadBytes = base64Decoder.decode(payvalue)
print(payloadBytes.map(_.toChar).mkString)
```

Any way it can be decoded and converted as json payload

Comment: What is your expected output? The value with the "line" key contains some binary encoded data part of which is some JSON schema string: `{"schema":"iglu:com.snowplowanalytics.snowplow/payload_data/jsonschema/1-0-4"...`. Are you going to extract it or do something else?

Comment: I am going to decode it and send back to another kinesis stream.
So requirement is read a kinesis stream decode and write back to another stream with the json payload